# BLOGGER: How to insert data from all posts of a blog

Tags: google-api, blogger

I've battled with this for hours and quite frankly I'm new to API's completely.

I've had blogger activated and generated an API key.

I have then used the following code to GET the posts (with YOUR-API-KEY) being the key i've generated:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953/posts?key=YOUR-API-KEY
```

**a) This isn't showing up on my site at all.

b) My site currently has Blog posts marked up in the following way:**

```
<section>
    <h2>BLOG TITLE</h2>
    <date>DATE OF POST GOES HERE</date>
    <p>BLOG CONTENT HERE</p>
</section>
```

**How can I display the posts to add this markup?**

I expected there to be a tonne of tutorials out there for this but I've been unable to find one concise enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this was public data I needed I just used simplexml_load_file to load the following:

http://www.blogger.com/feeds/blogId/posts/default.

I used the following tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ZLZkdiKGE0